# Kinetic energy of alpha-particle in $^{212}$Po decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

I'm writing a simulation to model alpha-decay, and I need to know the kinetic energies of the alpha particles that are emitted. In tables, e.g. for the decay of 212-Polonium, you would read

**$^{212}$Po -10.3649 MeV**

where the value given is the [mass excess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_excess) $\Delta M$. According to a nuclear physics book (Krane), the kinetic energy of the alpha particle is

$$K = \frac{Q}{1 + m_\alpha / m_{x'}}$$

where $Q$ is the [Q-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_value_%28nuclear_science%29), which is "the amount of energy released in the reaction", $m_\alpha$ is the mass of the alpha particle and $m_{x'}$ is the mass of the daughter nucleus.

I thought that $Q$ and $\Delta M$ were simply related by a factor of $c^2$,
$$Q = (\Delta M) c^2.$$
However, this gives the wrong answer. How can I calculate the kinetic energy of the alpha particle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint :You have masses (from parent nuclei mass you can get mass of daughter nuclei by subtracting mass of $\alpha$ particle  , and the Q value ie. the energy that gets liberated

and 
$931.5 \ MeV \approx 1 amu$ and so you can see the excess mass is easily negligible ie $<0.1amu$

---

> $^{212}Po \rightarrow \ ^{208}D + \ ^4\alpha$
>
> momentum is zero before and after the disintegration. => $m_D V_D=m_\alpha V_\alpha$
>
> So , net energy $$1/2m_DV_d^2+1/2m_\alpha V_\alpha^2=8.95412MeV$$
>     $$1/2m_dV_d^2=1/2V_d(m_\alpha V\alpha)=1/2\dfrac{m_\alpha   V_\alpha}{m_d}\times (m_\alpha V\alpha)=\dfrac{m_\alpha}{m_d}\times KE_\alpha$$ 
>   so, $$\Bigg(1+\dfrac{m_\alpha}{m_d}\Bigg)\times KE_\alpha=8.95412MeV$$
>   Now solve this to get the KE of $\alpha$ particle

Comment: thanks for the answer! according to this, then the last equation would just read $m_\alpha*V_\alpha^2 = 2 Ekin = 10.3649$ MeV, i.e. $E_{kin}^\alpha \approx 5$ Mev? which means that we are assuming that the Nucleus does not recoil?

Comment: No.$1/2m_dV_d^2=1/2V_d(m_\alpha V\alpha)=1/2\dfrac{m_\alpha   V_\alpha}{m_d}\times (m_\alpha V\alpha)=\dfrac{m_\alpha}{m_d}\times KE_\alpha$ , and u need to solve it.

Comment: sorry, I have been sitting behind the screen for too long ;-)

Comment: >@sebastian And now you can see it's same as in your book.

Comment: in German we say "I had plie-wood in front of my eyes". of course! thank you!

Comment: @sebastian How come it is 8.9MeV?

Comment: because the -10.3649 MeV are the mass excess ($\Delta M c^2$) which **is not** the same as the Q factor, it is **[listed here**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=212+Polonium), (which was kind of my question in the first place ;-))

Comment: BTW--The daughter is lead ($\mathrm{Pb}$).